# Change the way JSTree identifies leaf nodes

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I want to change the way JSTree identifies leaf nodes. Today, it checks for children property of the node to see if it is boolean true or an array with at least one child node. [Reference](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

I want to create a node property called isLeaf so that jsTree would understand that the node is openable for AJAX loading of the subtree.

I tried to override default [is_parent](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=is_parent) method, like this:

```
$.jstree.core.prototype.is_parent = function(node) {
    return !node.original.isLeaf;
};
```

But for some reason this method is not called for all tree nodes.

I am using [ngJsTree](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree)

Does anyone know how can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to deal with it by iterating over AJAX response and changing every node without children to children = true.

```
success : function(nodeRoot) {

    var validateChildrenArray = function(node) {

        if (!node.children || node.children.length === 0) {
            node.children = true;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
                validateChildrenArray(node.children[i]);
            }
        }

    };
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeRoot.length; i++) {
        validateChildrenArray(nodeRoot[i]);
    }
}
```

Waiting for a better solution...